# Need to build a JIRAclient using mvn

Tags: jira-rest-java-api

I am new to JIRA client usage. I am trying to create a REST client and create an issue in our JIRA. There are lot if example but none of them are working for me.

I am using mvn and eclipse on win7.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>jira</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-int</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>jira-int</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Atlassian Public Repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://maven.atlassian.com/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

For any version eclipse giving error:

Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:jar:3.0.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:pom:3.0.1 from http://maven.atlassian.com/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:pom:3.0.1 from/to central (http://maven.atlassian.com/public): EOFException    pom.xml    /jira-int    line 1    Maven Dependency Problem

Can some one provide me pom and sample client code to create an issue in my JIRA.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following dependencies:

```
<!-- Dependencies for Jira module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jiraClientVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jiraClientVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

where  ${jiraClientVersion} is the jira rest java client version.

Also I have added the following repository:

```
<repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
```

Then you can use all the libraries the jira rest java client provides.